# Preventing second votes in Comment Voting

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a question regarding a method to prevent second voting in a website where people can vote up or vote down a comment. Like Stackoverflow!! :)

The question is how I can keep track of whether a comment has already been voted by a logged in user. Lets assume this is for a online ecommerce store with reviews on products. Here's what I think:

- All reviews data is stored in a table called 'reviews'
- Field names: review_id, product_id, user_id, title, description, time_created, up_votes, down_votes, up_voters, down_voters
- up_votes and down_votes contain the number of votes voting it up or down
- up_voters and down_voters contain the user_id of the people who voted up or down in the format 1101.1102.1103 for users with user_id 1101, 1102 and 1103.

When a person clicks on the up vote button, the system will check if the current user's user_id matches anyone in up_voters. An explode function will turn 1101.1102.1103 into an array and in_array() will be used to check if the user has already voted.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That table will give you nightmares down the line. Just think of a hit product with 1K up_voters, your field will be 10K*4 characters long! Not just that, it will hinder your ability to make reports and study the data etc.

I don't know much about your needs but from what I can see in your table, I'd suggest the below.

```
review
user_id, product_id, type_of_vote, title, description, time_created
```

Use above table and use user_id, product_id as the key

OR

```
review
review_id, product_id, title, description, time_created

vote
review_id, user_id, type_of_vote
```

There are n number of ways to design tables for this. If it is an [Operational Data Store(ODS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_data_store) then you might want to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your design. If it's a warehouse then you may consider first table I mentioned above.

Comment: great! i'll put the votes in a seperate table... I'm wondering when scaling up to say 5000 products each with 50 votes, thats a table with 25K rows. Wonder if searching through the table will be slow

Comment: choose your primary key(PK) wisely. data access based on the PK will be fast as, AFAIK, most databases use unique index on the PK. You can also move the product_id to vote table.